# Quality check failing with sonarqube Nullpointer when using findFirst

Tags: java, java-stream

SonarQube quality fails with possible `NullPointer` in the method

When calling the method I'm checking !=null, but not passing through

```
private Asset findAsset(List<Asset> assets, Long assetId) {
    return assets.parallelStream()
                 .filter(ast -> ast.getAssetId().equals(assetId))
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(null);
}
```

Im trying the below code:

```
if (findAsset(assetCompositionList, pair.getKey()) != null) {
    assetMap.put(pair.getKey(),
            findAsset(assets, pair.getKey()).getAssetCode());
}
```

I was already checking `!=null` in `findAsset()` method when called.

Comment: Are you sure `pair` isn't null?

Comment: `findAsset(assets, pair.getKey())` could still be `null`, isn't it?

Comment: GBlodgett yes pair.key()  will not be null

Comment: Please include an [MCVE], including a complete stack trace

Comment: On which line you are getting warning, in IDE, specifically which method call, since your method is in a single line

Comment: Pratapi Hemant Patel  A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "findAsset()" can return null.

Comment: At which line sonar is pointing for possible exception?

Comment: @Naman looks like its not a duplicate question. The user not asking what is NPE and how to fix. Actually user asking why SonarQube is marking that code as possible NPE exception.

Comment: Error is at line `assetMap.put(pair.getKey(), findAsset(assets, pair.getKey()).getAssetCode());`. First collect result in a variable then check for null. `Asset asset = findAsset(assetCompositionList, pair.getKey());
if (asset != null) {
    assetMap.put(pair.getKey(), asset.getAssetCode());
}`

Since you are calling method twice, on first call null check is there, but on second call, there is no null check. Sonar is not intelligent enough to check same parameter is passed in both call. Question is marked duplicate so can't add answer now.

Comment: @ Pratapi Hemant Patel  yes just did that and came here to check if there is anyother solution. you suggested the same thank u :)

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel I agree that this was not duplicate of our canonical NPE question. Question is reopened so you can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is at line on second call of `findAsset` function.

`assetMap.put(pair.getKey(), findAsset(assets, pair.getKey()).getAssetCode());`

First collect result in a variable then check for null.

```
Asset asset = findAsset(assetCompositionList, pair.getKey());
if (asset != null) { 
    assetMap.put(pair.getKey(), asset.getAssetCode());
}
```

Since you are calling method twice, on first call null check is there, but on second call, there is no null check. Sonar is not intelligent enough to check same parameters are passed in multiple function call.